# Is it possible to save an interrupted computation?

Tags: interruption

I've got this really time consuming factoring problem. To decouple things a bit, I decided to start *Mathematica* using the command line interface (under [screen](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935)).

```
$ math
```

So my code is running, and I know that I can interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, but what I want to do is interrupt it, and then write the state of the process to disk, so that I can reboot. On Linux, there is a program called [CryoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/) which might work. Unfortunately, my computation is running on OS X.

I can detach from the screen session and re-attach to it, but if I reboot the machine I know it'll lose memory and the computation progress so far. My question is: can you save the state of a *Mathematica* computation that you interrupt (to disk and reloadable after a restart). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that there is a practical way to save the complete internal state and resume the computation where it was interrupted.  However, here's what you *can* do:

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, you get a prompt. If you type `i` at this prompt, you'll enter a ["dialogue"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Dialogs.html) with Mathematica.  You can examine the internal state, look at the values of all the variables, look at `Stack[]`, etc.  Evaluating `Return[]` will resume the computation. (Warning: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or `Quit` will still quit.)

If your computation is not *too* complicated, you *may* be able to extract enough information so you can resume later.  But the chances that this will work in practice are not great.  For example you can't extract a partial result from `Table` because it's not stored in a user-accessible variable.

For the future, the best thing you could do would be designing the computation to be interruptible by saving partial results into a variable.  For something that is already running at this moment, unfortunately the chances are slim.